# Editing a downloaded CSV in memory before writing

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Forewarning: I am very new to Python and programming in general. I am trying to use Python 3 to get some CSV data and making some changes to it before writing it to a file. My problem lies in accessing the CSV data from a variable, like so:

```
import csv
import requests

csvfile = session.get(url)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile.content)

for row in reader:
    do(something)
```

This returns:

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Googling revealed that I should be feeding the reader text instead of bytes, so I also attempted:

```
 reader = csv.reader(csvfile.text)
```

This also does not work as the loop works through it letter by letter instead of line by line. I also experimented with TextIOWrapper and similar options with no success. The only way I have managed to get this to work is by writing the data to a file, reading it, and then making changes, like so:

```
csvfile = session.get(url)

with open("temp.txt", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(csvfile.content)

with open("temp.txt", 'rU', encoding="utf8") as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        do(something)
```

I feel like this is far from the most optimal way of doing this, even if it works. What is the proper way to read and edit the CSV data directly from memory, without having to save it to a temporary file?

Comment: [This](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1572/python_for_beginners_reading_and_manipulating_csv_files) is probably worth looking at since you're just starting out.

Comment: what format is the data you're fetching from the url (xml, json, etc ?)

Comment: It should be plaintext but it is likely that I am missing or misunderstanding something. The relevant response headers are as such:
    Content-Disposition:"attachment; filename=data.csv"
    Content-Encoding:"gzip"
    Content-Type:"text/csv;charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to write to a temp file, here is what I would do, using the "csv" and "requests" modules:

```
import csv
import requests

__csvfilepathname__ = r'c:\test\test.csv'
__url__ = 'https://server.domain.com/test.csv'

def csv_reader(filename, enc = 'utf_8'):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding = enc) as openfileobject:
        reader = csv.reader(openfileobject)
        for row in reader:
            #do something
            print(row)
    return

def csv_from_url(url):
    line = ''
    datalist = []
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url)    
    for x in r.text.replace('\r',''):
        if not x[0] == '\n':
            line = line + str(x[0])
        else: 
            datalist.append(line)
            line = ''
    datalist.append(line)
    # at this point you already have a data list 'datalist'
    # no need really to use the csv.reader object, but here goes:
    reader = csv.reader(datalist)
    for row in reader:
        #do something
        print(row)
    return

def main():
    csv_reader(__csvfilepathname__)
    csv_from_url(__url__)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

not very pretty, and probably not very good in regards to memory/performance, depending on how "big" your csv/data is

HTH, Edwin.

Comment: Thanks. This yields the headers row correctly, but afterwards I run into this:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03c2' in position 12303: character maps to <undefined>

Any ideas?

Comment: @JSantos that looks to me like a double byte encoding, so you will have to figure out what encoding your source is using. utf_16_be or utf_16_le or some other encoding (there are many!!)... once you know the encoding of the source, you can convert the string to a unicode string using the correct encoding.